# Deno: error: Access is denied. (os error 5)

Tags: node.js, prisma, deno

I setup Prisma on Deno and everthing worked perfectly using this [article](https://www.prisma.io/docs/guides/deployment/deployment-guides/deploying-to-deno-deploy).

However, I decided to use Prisma on a local MySQL:

```
deno run -A --unstable npm:prisma generate
```

and import in my `main.ts`

```
import { PrismaClient } from './generated/client'

const prisma = new PrismaClient()
```

but got error "error: Access is denied. (os error 5)". Here is my code:

```
 deno run --A --unstable main.ts

...
error: Access is denied. (os error 5)
    at file:///C:/source/js/deno/test-api/main.ts:
```

need help please.

I used powershell windows 10 on administrator and other suggestions [here](https://github.com/denoland/deno/issues/5301), but still the same.

Answer (score 0):

Deno doesn't allow omission of `index.js`(or `.ts`).
Maybe

```
import { PrismaClient } from './generated/client'
```

should be

```
import { PrismaClient } from './generated/client/index.ts'
```